# Weight for BaggingClassifier in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, import, scikit-learn

I want to use different weight for BaggingClassifier in sklearn.
For Type with value 1,2,3 and for i need weight 1, 30, 30 and 30 respectedly.
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.fit

This is my code:

```
 sample_weight=[1,30,30,30]
bagging.fit(XTrain,yTrain,sample_weight)
```

This doesn't work. Could you please guide me what the correct format is?

based on the helps given here, i did the following:

```
bagging.fit(XTrain,yTrain,sample_weight=w)
```

and w shape is `('w.shape', (417, 1))` and `('XTrain.shape', (417, 7))`, `yTrain.shape (417,)`
i receive the following error:`ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (417,417) into shape (417,1)`

Answer (score 0):

The shape of `sample_weight` needs to be [equal to the number of items](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.BaggingClassifier.fit) in `XTrain`

```
sample_weight : array-like, shape = [n_samples] or None
```

Note however:

> Sample weights. If None, then samples are equally weighted. Note that this is supported only if the base estimator supports sample weighting.